# Persisted data in redeclared variables

Tags: javascript

How can the first `foo`'s data be persisted, even though the variable is redeclared?

To elaborate, the first `bar` property is still increased, despite that the object is redeclared. Each button has its own separate counter:

```
var foo = {
    bar: 1,
    bindClick: function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#first').on('click', function(){
            console.log(that.bar++);
        });
    }
};

foo.bindClick();

var foo = {
    bar: 1,
    bindClick: function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#second').on('click', function(){
            console.log(that.bar++);
        });
    }
};

foo.bindClick();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdzjx2d3/

Comment: since the original `foo` is still referenced, it is not destroyed. you have to implicitly do `delete foo.bar`

Comment: @Fabricator So you're saying that two `foo`s exists in parallel here?

Comment: Is this the code in its "natural habitat" or have you pulled it out to try to illustrate your situation?

Comment: Why are you re-declaring a variable in the same scope, anyway?

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney It's a minified example, but with identical behaviour. Why?

Comment: @filur interesting question! fettereddingoskidney, how does that matter?

Comment: Per both of my questions, redeclaring a variable in the same scope is odd. The reason I asked whether this code was in its "natural habitat" was to see what the true intent of this code was and whether redeclaring the variable in the same scope was actually necessary. It's probably not.

Comment: Okay, I get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var that = this;
```

This line is maintaining a reference to the original object; the first one you instantiated. Even when that variable name gets reused for something else, since that event listener, and that closure, still exist, it's still referenced someplace.

(Not gonna offer change suggestions, since you just seem curious as to the reasoning. Feel free to add more to your question if you have a particular desired behavior)

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a self executing function to to create a scope. inside the referenced foo is different than the outside foo therefore is not overwritten even if they have the same name

```
var foo = {
    bar: 1,
    bindClick: function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#first').on('click', function(){
            console.log(that.bar++);
        });
    }
};

foo.bindClick();

(function() {
    var foo = {
        bar: 1,
        bindClick: function() {
            var that = this;
            $('#second').on('click', function(){
                console.log(that.bar++);
            });
        }
    };

    foo.bindClick();
}())
```

Comment: I'm not asking for a fix. I would like the behavior explained. Also, first `foo` will still be accessible in your IIFE, so this makes no difference.

Comment: You ask how to persist. The fastest solution is not overwrite at all. I'll take a look again.

Comment: Downvoting for not getting the answer that you were looking for but never asked. Really??? Perhaphs you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @devconcept I boosted ya back up. same thing happened to me. Not sure who downvoted.

Comment: Sadly this could be a good question if it was properly asked. I also removed the poor voting on your answer. It took like half an hour to know what was really needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `var` off of the second foo. Redeclaring isn't going to actually 'wipe' the first object. Essentially, I believe that Javascript isn't completely overwriting the value for the `foo` variable - it's only overwriting the difference, which is the bindClick definition. The `foo` object(s) are still pointing to the same reference for `bar`, since that value hasn't been replaced with a reference to your new `foo`'s `bar` property.

```
var foo = {
    bar: 1,
    bindClick: function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#first').on('click', function(){
            console.log(that.bar++);
        });
    }
};

foo.bindClick();

foo = {
    bar: 1,
    bindClick: function(){
        var that = this;
        $('#second').on('click', function(){
            console.log(that.bar++);
        });
    }
};

foo.bindClick();
```

Are you trying to create two instances of the same object? If so, it might be better to do something like:

```
var foo = function() {
    this.bar = 0;
    this.bindClick = function() {
        this.bar++;
    }
}

var first = new foo();
first.bindClick();
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote because someone didn't give you the answer you're looking for, you should probably clarify that you're "JUST CURIOUS" in your post.